# Mean of values in some columns with Pandas/Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've just started with Pandas and Numpy a couple of months ago and I've learned already quite a lot thanks to all the threads here. But now I can't find what I need.

For work, I have created an excel sheet that calculates some figures to be used for re-ordering inventory. To practice and maybe actually use it, I'd wanted to give it a try to replicate the functionality in Python. Later I might want to add some more sophisticated calculations with the help of Scikit-learn.

So far I've managed to load a csv with sales figures from our ERP into a dataframe, calculate mean and std. The calculations have been done on a subset of the data because I don't know how to apply calculations only to the specific columns. The csv does also contain for example product codes and leadtimes and these should not be used for the average and std calculations. Not sure yet also how to merge this subset back with the original dataframe.

The reason why I didn't hardcode the column names is because the ERP reports the sales number over the past x no. of months, so the order of the columns will change througout the year and I want to keep them in chronological order.

My data from the csv looks like:

```
"code","leadtime","jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"
"001.002",60,299,821,351,614,246,957,968,939,125,368,727,231
"001.002",25,340,274,733,575,904,953,614,268,638,960,617,757
"001.002",130,394,327,435,767,377,699,424,951,972,717,317,264
```

What I've done so far and what is working fine. (This can be doe probably much easier/more efficient):

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import csv
import pandas as pd

sd = 1
csv_in = "data_in.csv"
csv_out = "data_out.csv"

# Use Pandas
df = pd.read_csv(csv_in,dtype={'code': str})

# Get no of columns and substract 2 for compcode and leadtime
cols = df.shape[1] - 2

# Create a subset and count the columns
df_subset = df.iloc[:, -cols:]
subset_cols = df_subset.shape[1]

# Add columns for std dev and average
df_subset = (df_subset.assign(mean=df_subset.mean(axis=1),
                             stddev=df_subset.std(axis=1, ddof=0))
            )
# Add columns for min and max values based on mean +/- std multiplied by factor sd
df_subset = (df_subset.assign(minSD=df_subset['mean'].sub(df_subset['stddev'] * sd),
                             maxSD=df_subset['mean'].add(df_subset['stddev'] * sd))

df_subset
```

Which gives me:

```
    jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec mean    stddev  minSD   maxSD
0   299 821 351 614 246 957 968 939 125 368 727 231 553.833333  304.262998  249.570335  858.096332
1   340 274 733 575 904 953 614 268 638 960 617 757 636.083333  234.519530  401.563804  870.602863
2   394 327 435 767 377 699 424 951 972 717 317 264 553.666667  242.398203  311.268464  796.064870
```

However for my next calculation I'm stuck again:
I want to calculate the average over values from the "month" columns and only the values that match the condition >= minSD and <= maxSD

So for row 0, I'm looking for the value (299+821+351+614+368+727)/6 = 530

How can I achieve this?
I've tried this, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
df_subset = df_subset.assign(avgwithSD=df_subset.iloc[:,0:subset_cols].values(where(df_subset.values>=df_subset['minSD'] & df_subset.values>=df_subset['maxSD'])).mean(axis=1))
```

Some help would be very welcome. Thanks

EDIT: With help I ended up using this to get further with my program

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import csv
import pandas as pd

# sd will determine if range will be SD1 or SD2
sd = 1

# file to use
csv_in = "data_in.csv"
csv_out = "data_out.csv"

# Function to calculate the mean of the values within the range between minSD and maxSD
def CalcMeanSD(row):
     months_ = row[2:14]
     min_SD = row[-2]
     max_SD = row[-1]
     return months_[(months_ >= min_SD) & (months_ <= max_SD)]

# Use Pandas
df = pd.read_csv(csv_in,dtype={'code': str})

# Define the month/data columns and set them to floatvalues
months_cols = df.columns[2:]
df.loc[:, months_cols] = df.loc[:, months_cols].astype('float64')

# Add columns for stddev and mean. Based on these values set new range between minSD and maxSD
df['stddev'] = df.loc[:,months_cols].std(axis=1, ddof=0)
df['mean'] = df.loc[:, months_cols].mean(axis=1)
df['minSD'] = df['mean'].sub(df['stddev'] * sd)
df['maxSD'] = df['mean'].add(df['stddev'] * sd)

# Add column with the mean of the new range
df['avgwithSD'] = np.nanmean(df.apply(CalcMeanSD, axis=1), axis=1)

df
```

Result is:

```
    code    leadtime    jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec stddev  mean    minSD   maxSD   avgwithSD
0   001.002 60  299.0   821.0   351.0   614.0   246.0   957.0   968.0   939.0   125.0   368.0   727.0   231.0   304.262998  553.833333  249.570335  858.096332  530.000000
1   001.002 25  340.0   274.0   733.0   575.0   904.0   953.0   614.0   268.0   638.0   960.0   617.0   757.0   234.519530  636.083333  401.563804  870.602863  655.666667
2   001.002 130 394.0   327.0   435.0   767.0   377.0   699.0   424.0   951.0   972.0   717.0   317.0   264.0   242.398203  553.666667  311.268464  796.064870  495.222222
3   001.002 90  951.0   251.0   411.0   469.0   359.0   220.0   192.0   250.0   818.0   768.0   937.0   128.0   292.572925  479.500000  186.927075  772.072925  365.000000
4   001.002 35  228.0   400.0   46.0    593.0   61.0    293.0   5.0 203.0   850.0   506.0   37.0    631.0   264.178746  321.083333  56.904588   585.262079  281.833333
5   001.002 10  708.0   804.0   208.0   380.0   531.0   125.0   500.0   773.0   354.0   238.0   805.0   215.0   242.371773  470.083333  227.711560  712.455106  451.833333
6   001.002 14  476.0   628.0   168.0   946.0   29.0    324.0   3.0 400.0   981.0   467.0   459.0   571.0   295.814225  454.333333  158.519109  750.147558  436.625000
7   001.002 14  92.0    906.0   18.0    537.0   57.0    399.0   544.0   977.0   909.0   687.0   881.0   459.0   333.154577  538.833333  205.678756  871.987910  525.200000
8   001.002 90  487.0   634.0   5.0 918.0   158.0   447.0   713.0   459.0   465.0   643.0   482.0   672.0   233.756447  506.916667  273.160220  740.673113  555.777778
9   001.002 130 741.0   43.0    976.0   461.0   35.0    321.0   434.0   8.0 330.0   32.0    896.0   531.0   326.216782  400.666667  74.449885   726.883449  415.400000
```

Comment: Starting with the original csv file you could try running this: `months = df.columns[2:];df[['std', 'mean', 'max', 'min']] = df.loc[:,months].agg( ['std', 'mean' , 'max' , 'min' ], axis=1 )`

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful as I don't need to create a subset anymore for (some?) calculations. But how can I set the ddof=0 for the std now?
This won't work: .agg( ['std(ddof=0)', 'mean' , 'max' , 'min' ], axis=1 )
This also not:".agg( ['std', 'mean' , 'max' , 'min' ], axis=1, ddof=0 )

Comment: It's good that you commented your code to show what each line is doing and what you expect from it - keep that habit up.  However, I think you should redo the question showing all of your code (like where `sd` comes from).  If you like feel free to use the line of code above if that jumps you where you want to be.  Then show what you need to do next with desired outcome included too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Instead of your original code:

```
# first part:
months_cols = df.columns[2:]
df.loc[:, months_cols] = df.loc[:, months_cols].astype('float64')
df['stddev'] = df.loc[:,months_cols].std(axis=1, ddof=0)
df['mean'] = df.loc[:, months_cols].mean(axis=1)
df['minSD'] = df['mean'].sub(df['stddev'] * sd)
df['maxSD'] = df['mean'].add(df['stddev'] * sd)


# second part: (the one that doesn't work for you)
def calc_mean_per_row_by_condition(row):
     months_ = row[2:14]
     min_SD = row[-2]
     max_SD = row[-1]
     return months_[(months_ >= min_SD) & (months_ <= max_SD)]

df['avgwithSD'] = np.nanmean(df.apply(calc_mean_per_row_by_condition, axis=1), axis=1)
```

Comment: Besides from the "FutureWarning" I get, it's only giving NaN values back with warning: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice

Comment: Yes, thank it's working after a small adjustment. `months_ = row[2:13]` needs to be set to `months_ = row[2:14]` to include the last month.